# How do use a static value in a value list XAML?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Let's say I have a `<Grid/>` and I am setting the `Margin` property on it. I want to reference a single static value in the list of values I am setting. For example:

```
<Grid Margin="1,22,3,7"/>
```

I want to do something like:

```
<Grid Margin="1,{x:Static SystemParameters.CaptionHeight},3,7"/>
```

I know that is the wrong syntax, but I want to do something like that. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Just declare the margin value in the verbose syntax:

```xml
<Grid>
  <Grid.Margin>
    <Thickness Left="1" Top="{x:Static SystemParameters.CaptionHeight}" Bottom="3" Right="7"/>
  </Grid.Margin>
</Grid>
```